# I want to apply a specific startup script to all the vms of a project but I don't want to use the normal way

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I want to apply a specific startup script but I don't want to use the normal way of putting this either in google cloud storage bucket or putting it the metadata field. So, I want to apply it for all the Virtual machines in a specific project. What is the best possible way to do this?

Comment: Either use Startup script on Cloud Storage (thing that you don't want), or create a custom image with your script in it. But it's not a good idea (for evolution test, bug fixing,...) prefer the option 1.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use startup script ? (The built-in one, not sure why you would run from cloud storage?)

[image: Option for startup script]